# how to get selected row when click on combobox in table

Tags: java

I have a table and at each row i have a combox of operator from which we can choose any operator and value1 field value 2 field. COMBO BOX DEFAULT OPERATOR IS " EQUAL TO".so my question is when u click on combobox in any row i should get the value of the selected row and get the operator which i am selecting such that i can perform some operation based on selected operator....
Or else if i change the combobox operator from in between to equal to i should get clear the value 2 field....
Help me get out of this..

Comment: Are you ask with JComboBox in Java SWT?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an event to know item in the combo is clicked.

Like this:

```
combo.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //doSomething();
    }
});
```

You have three methods to get current item selected:

> Will get the index of the item is order number.
>
> ```
> int selectedIndex = myComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
> ```

*-or-*

> Will get item selected with Object. You can do many method contains in this Object.
>
> `Object selectedObject = myComboBox.getSelectedValue();`

*-or-*

> Will get real values of item selected with string type.
> `String selectedValue = myComboBox.getSelectedValue().toString();`

You can see full example code at here (from @secario member):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyWind extends JFrame{

    public MyWind() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setSize(200, 50);
        field.setText("              ");

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.addItem("item1");
        comboBox.addItem("item2");

        //
        // Create an ActionListener for the JComboBox component.
        //
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //
                // Get the source of the component, which is our combo
                // box.
                //
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();

                Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                if(selected.toString().equals("item1"))
                field.setText("30");
                else if(selected.toString().equals("item2"))
                    field.setText("40");

            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(comboBox);
        getContentPane().add(field);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyWind().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```